# Accessing all Individual Values of a Nested Object Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, array.prototype.map

I'm trying to access the individual count values of each list object for each item to use them in an array. I've tried various map methods, but it keeps returning undefined. I need a dynamic approach to gather these counts so when more lists, items, locations, and counts are added, it will update.

**Data:**

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "List1",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Item1",
        locations: [
          { position: "a", count: 20 },
          { position: "b", count: 30 },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Item2",
        locations: [
          { position: "c", count: 40 },
          { position: "d", count: 50 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "List2",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Item3",
        locations: [
          { position: "e", count: 60 },
          { position: "f", count: 70 },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: "Item4",
        locations: [
          { position: "g", count: 80 },
          { position: "h", count: 90 },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

**Desired Result:**

```js
const onlyCounts = [20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90];
```

**Any tips or info would be appreciated, Thanks!**

Comment: _"I've tried various map methods"_... such as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a generalized solution because you aren't sure of the nested object shape/keys/depth, here is a recursive solution that works so long as your data doesn't have any cycles.

```
const getCounts = (value) =>
  value.flatMap((el) =>
    Object.entries(el).flatMap(([key, value]) => {
      if (key === "count") return [value];
      if (Array.isArray(value)) return getCounts(value);
      return [];
    })
  );
```

```js
const data = [
  {
    name: "List1",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Item1",
        locations: [
          { position: "a", count: 20 },
          { position: "b", count: 30 }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Item2",
        locations: [
          { position: "c", count: 40 },
          { position: "d", count: 50 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "List2",
    items: [
      {
        name: "Item3",
        locations: [
          { position: "e", count: 60 },
          { position: "f", count: 70 }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Item4",
        locations: [
          { position: "g", count: 80 },
          { position: "h", count: 90 }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const getCounts = (value) =>
  value.flatMap((el) =>
    Object.entries(el).flatMap(([key, value]) => {
      if (key === "count") return [value];
      if (Array.isArray(value)) return getCounts(value);
      return [];
    })
  );

console.log(getCounts(data))
```

Really generalized solution

```
const getFieldArray = (value, field) =>
  value.flatMap((el) =>
    Object.entries(el).flatMap(([key, value]) => {
      if (key === field) return [value];
      if (Array.isArray(value)) return getFieldArray(value, field);
      return [];
    })
  );

console.log(getFieldArray(data, 'count'));
```

Comment: Exactly! That's what I was trying to ask but didn't know how to ask it. Thanks again Drew. I learned that you can use a recursive method similar to @Phils, which allows you to target a key string nested data utilizing the flat map() prototype. This way I can just pass a string variable as a case so it's more automated.

Comment: @pc.dependency Welcome. Yup, you could certainly adjust this to also pass a "target" key if you wanted.